# Making vertical list scroll on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical list in my navigation which is longer than the screens height. I would like it so that when I start to hover over the list the list will start in move up but only when the mouse is around half way down the list.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet?

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the window or move the list up? It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: I have tried using hoverscroll http://rascarlito.free.fr but can't seem to get it to work, I think its because the list is greater than the height of the screen.

Comment: @BryanDowning : Move down the list.

Comment: @BryanDowning : How would I go about scrolling down the window when scrolling down the list?

Comment: When the user is 'half way' on the *visible portion* of the list, or past the half way point *of* the list?

Comment: When they go past the half way portion of the list.

Comment: If i've understend you need somethings like this: `$('li').on('hover', function(){ if($(this).offset().top > ($('ul').height() /2)){ console.log('animate'); } })` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, is below:

```
var ul = $('ul:first'),
    ulHeight = ul.outerHeight();

ul.on('mousemove',
            function(e){
                var win = $(window),
                    cST = win.scrollTop();
                if (e.pageY>=(ulHeight/2)){
                    win.scrollTop(cST + 20);
                }
                else {
                    win.scrollTop(cST - 20);
                }
            });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw6Xw/4/).

This is based upon the halfway point of the list itself, and therefore relies on that halfway point being visible on the page itself.

To make it slightly more functional, the `ul` is within a containing element, and the scrolling is based upon the being past the halfway point of that containing element:

```
var div = $('#wrap'),
    wrapHeight = div.height(),
    listHeight = div.find('ul').outerHeight();

div.on('mousemove',
            function(e){
                var cPointY = e.pageY,
                    cST = div.scrollTop();
                if (cPointY >= (wrapHeight/2)) {
                    div.scrollTop(cST + 15);
                }
                else {
                    div.scrollTop(cST - 15);
                }
            });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw6Xw/3/).

---

**Edited** to add a further option that scrolls the list element up or down depending on the position of the cursor within the containing element:

```
var div = $('#wrap'),
    wrapScreenHeight = div.height(),
    wrapHeight = div.outerHeight(),
    listHeight = div.find('ul').outerHeight();

div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageY,
        dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
    div.scrollTop((listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight);

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw6Xw/6/).
​
References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/).
- [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Comment: This is exactly the effect I'm after the only problem I am having with the second example is that when I move the mouse up the menu it wont go back up the menu or move the screen back up. Any ideas?

Comment: Really? What browser/platform are you using? I've only tested in Chrome 20/Win XP, and it works perfectly there... =/

Comment: I think I need to make it so that if the mouse is moving upwards on the list even though its over half way in the list then start moving up?

Comment: I apologise I meant the first example.

Comment: Nearly, It doesn't go to the bottom of the list any more.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FDp2J/ this works perfectly I just need it to stop when the mouse stops.

Comment: According to the last version you provided in the answear i have a problem making it work with my current layout, i guess the math behind the whole scrolling isn't perfect, since to make it work i had to put a little workaround in the code...
this is my jsfiddle demostration of the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/bw6Xw/398/ (it doesn't scroll correctly to the end of the list)
and this is the one working with my workaround
http://jsfiddle.net/bw6Xw/399/ (i added a -100 at the end of the code)
but the workaround is not adaptative, and i can't understand the math behind the code, can you improve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be animated (and this case horizontal):

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);};
})();

var div = $('#menu3'),
    wrapScreenWidth = div.width(),
    wrapHeight = div.outerWidth(),
    listWidth = div.find('tr').outerWidth();
var go = 0;
function anim(){
    var act = Math.round(div.scrollLeft()),
        diff = Math.abs(act-go);
    if(diff)
        div.scrollLeft(div.scrollLeft()+ (act<go?1:-1)*diff*0.03);      
    window.requestAnimFrame(anim);                  
};

anim();

div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageX,
        dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
    go = Math.max(0,Math.round((listWidth * dP) - wrapScreenWidth));

});
```